# How to extract particular url from HTML tags using UNIX commands

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to extract a link `http://www.rediff.com/news` from the below `<a>` tag

`<a href="http://www.rediff.com/news" onclick="trackURL('http://track.rediff.com/click?url=___http://www.rediff.com/news___&cmp=news1_nav&lnk=news1_nav&nsrv1=ushome');return false;"><div class="n_tabnormal">News</div></a>`

using some Unix command. Please No hard coding for this.

Answer (score 1):

Using XML/HTML parsers is a right way to manipulate XML/HTML data:

[***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) solution:

```
sed 's/&/&amp;/g' yourfile | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//a[div/text() = "News"]/@href' -n
```

The output:

```
http://www.rediff.com/news
```

---

- `sed 's/&/&amp;/g'` - to convert ampersand `&` as a special char into HTML entity
- `//a[div/text() = "News"]/@href` - xpath expression, extracts `href` attribute value of `a` tag if it has child node `div` with text `News`